# R - enter basic formula

Tags: r

I am new to R and struggling to understand its quirks.  I'm trying to do something which should be really simple, but is turning out to be apparently very complicated.

I am used to Excel, SQL and Minitab, where you can enter a value in one column which includes references to other columns and parameters.  However, R doesn't seem to be allowing me to do this.

I have a table with (currently) four columns:

```
                               Date Pallets Lt Tt
            1  28/12/2011     491 NA NA
            2  29/12/2011     385 NA 0.787890411
            3  30/12/2011     662 NA NA
            4  31/12/2011      28 NA NA
            5  01/01/2012      46 NA NA
            6  02/01/2012     403 NA NA
            7  03/01/2012     282 NA NA
            8  04/01/2012     315 NA NA
            9  05/01/2012     327 NA NA
            10 06/01/2012     458 NA NA
```

and have a parameter "beta", with a value which I have assigned as 0.0002.

All I want to do is assign a formula to rows 3:10 which is: 
beta*(Pallets t - Pallets t-1)+(1-beta)*Tt t-1.

I thought that the appropriate code might be:

```
Table[3:10,4]<-beta*(Table[3:10,"Pallets"]-Table[2:9,"Pallets"])+(1-beta)*Table[2:9,"Tt"]
```

However, this doesn't work. The first time I enter this formula, it generates:

```
Date Pallets Lt        Tt
            1  28/12/2011     491 NA        NA
            2  29/12/2011     385 NA 0.7878904
            3  30/12/2011     662 NA 0.8431328
            4  31/12/2011      28 NA        NA
            5  01/01/2012      46 NA        NA
            6  02/01/2012     403 NA        NA
            7  03/01/2012     282 NA        NA
            8  04/01/2012     315 NA        NA
            9  05/01/2012     327 NA        NA
            10 06/01/2012     458 NA        NA
```

So it's generated the correct answer for the second item in the series, but not for any of the subsequent values.

It seems as though R doesn't automatically update each row, and the relationship to each other row, when you enter a formula, as Excel does.  Having said that, Excel actually would require me to enter the formula in cell [4,Tt], and then drag this down to all of the other cells.  Perhaps R is the same, and there is an equivalent to "dragging down" which I need to do?

Finally, I also noticed that when I change the value of the beta parameter, through, e.g. `beta<-0.5`, and then print the Table values again, they are unchanged - so the table hasn't updated even though I have changed the value of the parameter.

Appreciate that these are basic questions, but I am very new to R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, the computations are not made "cell by cell", but are vectorised - in your example, R takes the vectors `Table[3:10,"Pallets"]`, `Table[2:9,"Pallets"]` and `Table[2:9,"Tt"]` as they are at the moment, computes the resulting vector, and finally assigns it to `Table[3:10,4]`.

If you want to make some computations "cell by cell", you have to use the `for` loop:

```
beta <- 0.5
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1:12, v2 = 0)
for (i in 3:10) {
    df[i, "v2"] <- beta * (df[i, "v1"] - df[i-1, "v1"]) + (1 - beta) * df[i-1, "v2"]
}
df
   v1        v2
1   1 0.0000000
2   2 0.0000000
3   3 0.5000000
4   4 0.7500000
5   5 0.8750000
6   6 0.9375000
7   7 0.9687500
8   8 0.9843750
9   9 0.9921875
10 10 0.9960938
11 11 0.0000000
12 12 0.0000000
```

As it comes to your second question, R will never update any values on its own (imagine having set manual calculation in Excel). So you need to repeat the computations after changing beta.

Comment: Thanks for the very clear and good answer. So what do I do, then, if I have two columns in Excel whose value depends on each other? In Excel, if you enter the formula in column 1 and drag it down, then enter the formula in column 2, and drag it down, Excel automatically updates the values of both columns depending on the values of all the cells. How would one accomplish this in R?

Comment: Glad that helped. R and other programming languages just do not work that way. You have to "send" the code to the interpreter to see the result

Answer (score 1):

Although it's generally a bad design, but you can iterate over rows in a loop:

```
Table$temp <- c(0,diff(Table$Palletes,1))
prevTt = 0

for (i in 1:10)
{
  Table$Tt[i] = Table$temp * beta + (1-beta)*prevTt
  prevTt = Table$Tt[i]
}

Table$temp <- NULL
```

Comment: Good answer, but have already marked the below reply as answer.